CraftCMS S3 Plugin "Unable to write stream to..."
I've setup S3 for Craft plugin, setup the file system, put in the credentials. Fetched the bucket using the Control Panel (Refresh) option. (So it must have permissions to read) though when trying to upload an asset I get the error Unable to write stream to asset_name.png
I've done the following:

Created an IAM User with S3 Full Priv.
Created a bucket, nothing more.
Added IAM User credentials into the S3 File system settings.

Any help would be great.

I'm having the same issue :(

Check the settings for the filesystem in project.yaml.
I had an issue like this, where I could not upload images and image transforms were failing. I found that my images volume settings, in project.yaml had expires: ' seconds', which seemed odd.
I changed that to expires: '', ran php craft up and my images volume then behaved as expected.
